# Substring SQL Select

Tags: string, substring, sql-server-2014

A single cell will contain a string like the following:

```
[{"Code":"C015","Index":0,"Message":"blah blah blah","FailSeverity":2},{"Code":"W012","Index":0,"Message":"blah blah blah","FailSeverity":1}]
```

I am interested in pulling out all of the Codes from the single string above. I.E. I want the "C015" and "W012" from the example above and nothing else.

I've seen the Substring() function but am not too sure of how to implement it in this scenario or that I fully understand it as a function.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Depending on that, there are different builtin functions to treat this as json instead of mucking with substrings.

Comment: The DBMS we use is SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: Management Studio **IS NOT A DBMS!!**  It's just a query and schema tool, and it can connect to many different versions and editions of Sql Server or even some non-Sql Server databases.

Comment: As for the question, if you can update to Sql Server 2016, there is native JSON support. But generally, if you're gonna care about this stuff you need to build tables and columns in your schema to handle individual values, rather than big blogs of text

Comment: Ok I am misunderstanding what is being asked then, perhaps you can clarify that up a bit? In regards to updating that unfortunately is not an option for us at this time.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I think you've want to employ a good tally based string splitter function. In this case I'm using Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(8000) = '[{"Code":"C015","Index":0,"Message":"blah blah blah","FailSeverity":2},{"Code":"W012","Index":0,"Message":"blah blah blah","FailSeverity":1}]';

WITH 
    cte_GetCodes AS (
    SELECT 
        CodeValue = CASE WHEN LAG(dsk.Item, 2) OVER (ORDER BY dsk.ItemNumber) = 'Code' THEN dsk.Item END 
    FROM
        dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@String, '"') dsk
    )
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    cte_GetCodes gc
WHERE 
    gc.CodeValue IS NOT NULL;
```

Results...

```
CodeValue
----------
C015
W012
```

Comment: I think I was a bit unclear with what I was asking. I am searching for the cell that contains those messages anyways so I am looking to search for it and remove all the extra data in a single query if that makes sense?

Comment: @ChaseWhitehead SQL Server doesn't have "cells" so no... Still not making sense. If you want to make sense, start by updating your post with some actual test data and show the exact outcome you're looking for based on the supplied test data.